# How do I update to Python 2.7?

Tags: 10.10, python

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 which comes by default installed with Python 2.6, however some applications that I want to use require 2.7 and I want to update.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5):

It is already in the official repositories: http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/python2.7

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7
```

You then execute `python2.7`

P.S. Support for ubuntu 10.10 ends in April 2012: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: When I do this, the command `python` still uses 2.6, and using `python2.7` would cause problems for me when installing modules. Is there a way to replace it over 2.6?

Comment: May I ask what kind of problems? :) You can link python to use python2.7, but I **wouldn't** suggest that, `/usr/bin/python` is used by most python packages in ubuntu and might cause problems if you attempt to change it. If you want to use python 2.7 for your program, use on top of the myfile.py `#!/usr/bin/python2.7` and `chmod +x myfile.py`. Then run it as `./myfile.py`

Comment: ..or just upgrade your ubuntu. 11.04 has 2.7 as default: http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/python

Comment: The problem is that whenever I install a Python module, say for example `python-twitter`, it installs it but for the 2.6/default installation, so I would be unable to use it while using python2.7

Comment: There is also a python-twitter package :) But you can always link the .py library files/folders in the according 2.7 directory, I think it's `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`

Comment: I tried copying those files, but still doesn't recognize the module when called.

Comment: Hm.. maybe you forget using `python2.7 setup.py`? Also, if the package uses setup.py for installation, you can change the directory: `sudo python2.7 setup.py install --libdir=/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` (or something like that, use --help if it doesn't work)

Comment: I don't use any setup for the modules I used, I just install them with apt-get

Comment: I'm going to suggest, as medigeek has, that you upgrade your Ubuntu version after backing up critical data.  Ubuntu 11.04 uses Python 2.7 by default, and it would remove a ton of issues you are having out of the equation.

Answer (score 3):

The [Deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes) is helpful for old and new versions of Python.

Lucid through Precise is supported with versions 2.x and 3.x available. Since you are looking for 10.10, the direct link is:

> https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes?field.series_filter=maverick

Answer (score 1):

1. **Update Ubuntu 10.10 sources** ([credit](https://askubuntu.com/a/91821)).

   Because [10.10 is no longer supported](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2012/04/10/ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat-end-of-life-reached-on-april-10-2012/).

   ```
   sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. **Install `add-apt-repository` command** ([credit](http://linuxg.net/how-to-fix-error-sudo-add-apt-repository-command-not-found/)):

   This stops you from getting the `sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found` error in the next step.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
   ```
3. **Install [Deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes)** ([credit](http://kovshenin.com/2010/installing-python-2-5-on-ubuntu-linux-10-10/)):

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. **Install Python 2.7**:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python2.7
   ```
5. **Profit!**

   ```
   $ python2.7 --version
   Python 2.7.4
   ```

---

**Edit:** You can also install python 3.3 this way. Just replace step 4 with:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.3
```

Same goes for python 2.4, 2.5, 3.1, 3.2, etc.